# Count neighbors turtles of a specific patch and report true or false

Tags: netlogo

Hello i will try to be quick
I have a room with a fire that expands , and i have two exits , all i want to do is say to agents that if a door is blocked by fire then to go to the other one. i came up with something like this but not result.

```
to doorblock
show count neighbors with [pcolor = 77] ;; the patch color of the two doors
end

;;to go 

  ask smarts [    ;;smarts are the agents inside the room that need to get oout
    if [ doorblock > 5 ]    
   [ set target one-of sexits]]  ;;sexits is the other door
```

Anyone got a better idea? Thanks

Comment: The little bit of code posted here is hard to figure out. Unless you tell us more about your model, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: One possible hint: you are running your `doorblock` reporter in the context of your `smarts` agents, so the call to `neighbors` in `doorblock` will report the current neighbors of the `smart` that is running it, which may not be what you want.

Comment: `to doorblock show` should be `to-report doorblock report`, and `if [ doorblock > 5 ]` should just be `if doorblock > 5`

Comment: @nicolas Hello again ! The fire is represented with turtles that expand as time passes (just some red turtles) , the doors are represented like this :`set-default-shape nexits "house"` and `set-default-shape sexits "house"` (nexit  north , sexit south) and  depending on where  the agent is  he has the specific target for the door so : `ask smarts  [
  ifelse pycor > 0
  [ set target one-of nexits]
  [ set target one-of sexits]
  face target]`
The agents that facing a block door might be next to it (2-3 patches away ) or they can be  more far away (7-9) patches since they allocate randomly.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so if I understood correctly, you want your agents to take a look at the door that is their current target, check if that door has more than 5 fire agents around it, and choose another target door if that is the case.

If your fire agents are just red turtles (with no specific breed), you probably want something like this:

```
ask smarts [
  if count ([ turtles-on neighbors ] of target) with [ color = red ] > 5 [
    if-else ([ breed ] of target = sexits )
      [ set target one-of nexits ]
      [ set target one-of sexits ]
  ]
]
```

The key primitives here are:

- [`neighbors`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors), that will give you the *patches* around a turtle (the patches around `target`, in this case)
- [`turtles-on`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-on), that will give you the *turtles* that are on members of a patch set (here, that will be the turtles that are on the patches that are the `neighbors` of `target`)
- and finally, [`with`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with) allows you to get only the turtles from an agentset that satisfy some condition (here, we use it to get only the red turtles that represent the fires).

You should also try to understand the [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) primitive.

And I guessed you wanted to assign a new target that was of a different breed than the previous one (south if north, north if south) but that's up to you.

Comment: well the fire agents are a specific breed named (fires fire) so i a guess  i will change the [ color = red ] with the name of the  fire agents?

Comment: Ah, that makes things even simpler. `turtles-on` has a special `<breeds>-on` form, where you can plug in the name of your breed. `([ turtles-on neighbors ] of target) with [ color = red ]` simply becomes `[ fires-on neighbors ] of target`.

Comment: BTW, when you ask a question, information like "the fire agents are a specific breed named (fires fire)" is important information to give (a lot more important than the shape or the color, usually).

Comment: This is great in the context where you want turtles of a particular breed though.  I was having trouble getting it to bind "with breed" correctly to the turtles not the patches.  Thanks!