# Netlogo Patch Commands

Tags: patch

is there a way to ask a patch to do something if it has a specific number of turtles on it? I don't know the exact commands for this, but it would look something like this

```
ask patch -10 0 [ 
   if 10 turtles are on this patch [ 
      ask patch 5 5 [ 
         set color red 
           ]
         ]
      ]
```

Comment: Yep, use the primitives `count` and `turtles-here`.  Check out @Nicolas's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995510/count-neighbors-turtles-of-a-specific-patch-and-report-true-or-false) for the answer to a similar issue.